# c# textbox-as-filename problems

Tags: c#, textbox, ms-word, filenames, office-interop

I have been trying to make a program and it saves mechanics invoices. So I have got this far;

```
oWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:/BMW/Invoices/" + Regbox.Text + "/thing.doc");
```

which saves the word doc in a folder that is specified by the registration of the bike - this works fine. but what I really want is the date to be used as a filename...I couldn't figure that out, so I made a date label and plan on using the text from it as the filename instead (I know, its a long way round...but it works). Anyways, I have tried;

```
oWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:/BMW/Invoices/" + Regbox.Text + "/" + label19.Text + ".doc");
```

this was an "invalid filename"

```
oWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:/BMW/Invoices/" + Regbox.Text + "/label19.Text.doc");
```

this saved it as "label19.Text.doc"

```
oWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:/BMW/Invoices/" + Regbox.Text + "/" + label19.Text, ".doc");
```

This threw the error "(DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)"

All I need to do is get label19 text to work as a filename with a .doc extension...or another way of getting the date as a filename

Comment: What is the value of label19.Text when you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use current date as file name then you can use:

```
oWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:/BMW/Invoices/" + Regbox.Text + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".doc")
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it worked. It is always the simple things that are more frustrating when i can't figure them out haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate the file name in an string variable:

```
string filename = "C:/BMW/Invoices/" + Regbox.Text + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy");
```

and then pass it to [`SaveAs2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx) method:

```
oWord.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(filename, ".doc");
```